# Hosting A Service as A WCF Service

Tags: wcf, service, hosting, wcf-hosting

I have two .cs files in one i will specify the Interfaces, and in another file i will implement the interfaces. Now i want to host Service as a WCF Service on IIS.
In another way How to host the already existing service(Functionality)  as a WCF Service. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS: Please help yourself by showing the source code in the two .cs file so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. put your two *.cs files into your `App_Code` directory in a web site and let ASP.NET compile then as needed. You will need to create a service file something like this:

   **YourService.svc**

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
       Service="YourService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/YourService.cs" %>
   ```
2. put your two *.cs files into a separate class-library project and compile them into a DLL which you put into the `\bin` directory in your web site/web application. You will need to create a service file something like this:

   **YourService.svc**

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="YourService"  %>
   ```

This service file tells the IIS runtime how to handle incoming requests for the `http://(yourserver)/(virtualdirectory)/YourService.svc` URL.

Now, once everything is setup, you should be able to connect to your service at the service URL using a tool like the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to send SOAP requests (and receive back responses)